# Booting HDD externally to Windows

Tags: windows, hard-drive

[English is not my first language.]

I got an old HP Compaq NC6220, and I have a problem with it.
This laptop has a HDD IDE  connector to the board (not originally IDE, from an older connector to IDE), and I'm a guy with up to three SATA HDDs.
I am too broke right now to afford an IDE hard drive.

I tried looking for a small cover that could turn the SATA connector into an IDE but I was told no such thing exists, but I doubt that.
So, now I am left with one choice, the three HDDs I mentioned are loaded with installed Windows, so I am trying to boot my HDD externally to Windows (did all the necessary boot order ceremony and saved it) but it didn’t boot to Windows, I read a lot of articles concerning this issue but couldn't find what satisfies me.

I noticed some lights at the edge of most HP laptops (charging, power and HDD activity LED) and I also noticed if it detect HDD or CD the HDD LED blinks But when I connected my HDD externally it didn't blink, so I figured the laptop didn’t detect it, although my external HDD enclosure is working perfectly fine.

So my question is how do I go about it?
Do I have to reconfigure or partition or do some little trick to the HDD on disk management on another laptop to make it possible to boot externally to Windows?

Comment: Depending on how old your laptop is you might not be able to boot from an external drive. How did you actually attach the drive to your laptop? What do you mean by its not originally IDE?

Comment: its 2006 (that's how old it is) and the bios boot order setup has a usb hard drive in its configuration, so i made it a higher priority over others by making it the first.
.
. i think its called scsi connector.
one end SCSI and the other end IDE hdd holes..

Comment: What kind of error are you seeing when you try to boot? Are you able to start a OS setup/LiveCD from e.g. a USB stick? As you're using USB you won't see the HDD LED flash.

Comment: i haven't tried out any usb storage devices only except from the external hdd and some external devices such as mouse and keyboard.
i only get the errors of a missing internal hdd.
i also tried to do some setting in the bios environment such a way that when i power the laptop its shows up the bootable devices for a specific time.
its only shows notebook mulitbay(no external and internal drive seen)...

Comment: i think the problem is from the hard drive...i have been goggling for the past few hours and i came across somethings, like windows to go, certified drive, windows 8 enterprises..... all these will enable the drive to boot into windows. but i need to get a clearer picture on how all this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that but you can install and completely use windows over USB.

I'm talking about a full working instal. NOT just putting the iso on USB. The USB is actually the OS of windows.

Your mileage may vary.

https://www.easyuefi.com/wintousb/

It has its own set of problems like you can't use page file so if you don't have enough ram it wont work well. But it does actually work pretty good with older computers.

Use at your own risk! I can say it does work!!!

Comment: Use windows 10 if you can because it will have a higher success rate if you cant get windows 7 to work. Try using windows 7 first if the computer is really old.